Inequality for hermitian matrices
Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be a complete system of orthogonal projections on $\mathbf R^n, n \geq 2$ (i.e., $p_i^2=p_i=p_i^*$ and $p_1+p_2=\bf{1}$) and $S_1, S_2$ be two hermitian operators such that $S_i \geq c_i \mathbf1$, where $c_i$ are positive ($i=1,2$) and $\mathbf 1$ denotes the identity operator on $\mathbf R^n.$ The inequalities mean that $S_i - c_i \mathbf1$ are positive semidefinite for $i=1,2.$ I would like to know if also
$S_1p_1S_1 + S_2p_2S_2 \geq c \mathbf1$ for a positive $c.$

No. For example, let
\begin{align*}
p_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ p_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ S_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ S_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
S_1p_1S_1 + S_2p_2S_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
which is not positive definite, so $c = 0$ the the largest $c$ possible.

Thanks. For an application, that I needed, I had to add that S_1 and S_2 are supposed to commute, i.e., S_1 S_2 = S_2 S_1, which might change the answer. But thanks for the nice  solution.

@Svata - if they commute then I’m pretty sure the answer switches to Yes. Feel free to post another question.
