Inequality for commuting hermitian operators
Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be a complete system of orthogonal projections on $R^n$, $n\geq 2$ (i.e., $p^2_i=p_i=p^*_i$ and $p_1+p_2=\bf{1}$) and $S_1,S_2$ be two commuting hermitian operators on $R^n$ (i.e., $S_1S_2=S_2S_1$ and $S_i^T=S_i$) such that $S_i≥c_i \bf{1}$, where $c_i$ are positive for $i=1,2,$ and $\bf{1}$ denotes the identity operator on $R^n$. The inequalities mean that $S_i−c_i\bf{1}$ are positive semidefinite for $i=1,2$. I would like to know if also $S_1p_1S_1+S_2p_2S_2≥c\bf{1}$ for a positive $c$.

Yes. Since $S_1$, $S_2$ commute, there exists an orthonormal basis in which they are both diagonal: $S_1={\rm diag}\,(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $S_2={\rm diag}\,(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, $a_i\geqslant c_1,b_i\geqslant c_2$ for all $i$. It follows that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\langle S_1x,S_2x\rangle=\sum a_ib_ix_i^2\geqslant c_1c_2\|x\|^2$. Thus, the angle between $S_1x$ and $S_2x$ is bounded away from $\pi/2$, and it can not occur that simultaneously $S_1x$ is close to the kernel of $p_1$ and $S_2x$ is close to the kernel of $p_2$. Hence for unit vector $x$, $\langle S_1p_1S_1+S_2p_2S_2x,x\rangle=\langle p_1S_1x,S_1x\rangle+\langle p_2S_2x,S_2x\rangle$ is bounded away from 0.

I do not consider it as a proof. In <S_1p_1S_1x + S_2p_2 S_2, x> =<p_1 S_1, S_1 x> + <p_2 S_2 x, S_2 x>, that You wrote, there is no term with S_1 S_2 (= S_2 S_1), so the condition was not used. For non-commuting S_1 and S_2 it is disproved in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483698/inequality-for-hermitian-matrices/483703?noredirect=1#comment1259871_483703 .

This condition was used before.

I somehow understand Your argument, but why the following cannot happen? S_1 x is not close to the kernel of p_1, but S_2 x is close to the kernel of p_2, or indeed is in the kernel of p_2. Then <p_1 S_1 x, S_1 x> + <p_2 S_2 x, S_2 x> = <p_1 S_1 x, S_1 x> which then cannot be estimated by c<x,x> but rather by c<x_1,x_1>. This can't happen?

$\langle S_1x,S_2x\rangle = \langle p_1 S_1x,S_2x\rangle + \langle S_1x,p_2 S_2x\rangle$
$\leq |p_1 S_1x| |S_2x| +  |p_2 S_2x| |S_1x|$
$\leq max(|S_1x|,|S_2x|) \ (\langle x,S_1 p_1 S_1x\rangle^{1/2} + \langle x,S_2 p_2 S_2x\rangle^{1/2})$
$\leq 2 \ max(|S_1x|,|S_2x|) \ ((\langle x,S_1 p_1 S_1x\rangle + \langle x,S_2 p_2 S_2x\rangle)/2)^{1/2}$
$\leq 2 \ max(|S_1|,|S_2|) \ |x| \ ((\langle x,S_1 p_1 S_1x\rangle + \langle x,S_2 p_2 S_2x\rangle)/2)^{1/2}$

But $S_1x$ is of order of $x$

jjcale: Thanks a lot.
